# networkX node_connected_component not implemented for directed type

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

I use networkX to build a directed graph, and I need to find the sub-graph that containing a special node. I try node_connected_component, but it can't implemented for directed graph, is there other function that can implement for directed graph in networkX?

Comment: Does the fact that the connections are directional influence your decision whether nodes are connected? Specifically. in the graph `A->B<->C`, would you consider `A` to be part for the connected component of `C`? If so, you can just convert the graph to an undirected one and find the connected component in that graph (`nx.to_undirected` IIRC).

Answer (score 4):

As someone mentioned it depends what you call a connected component in a directed graph:

1. Strongly connected components:

   There is a directed path between node A to node B and another from node B to node A.
2. Weakly connected components:

   There is a directed path from node A to node B but not necessarily from node B to node A.

What you can do:

```
def get_strongly_cc(G, node):
    """ get storngly connected component of node""" 
    for cc in nx.strongly_connected_components(G):
        if node in cc:
            return cc
    else:
        return set()

def get_weakly_cc(G, node):
    """ get weakly connected component of node""" 
    for cc in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
        if node in cc:
            return cc
    else:
        return set()


weak_component = get_weakly_cc(G, node)  # Weakly connected component of node in G
strong_component = get_strongly_cc(G, node)  # Strongly connected component of node in G
```

Comment: You can definitely do better than this by looking at the code used for the strongly and weakly connected components https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/strongly_connected.html#strongly_connected_components and https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/weakly_connected.html#weakly_connected_components and just do a single iteration of those algorithms starting from the node chosen.

Comment: You can definitely do better than this in terms of  efficiency, the result will be the same though. The task of tweaking the algorithms you mentioned is worth it for large graphs, which depend ultimately on OP needs (which weren't specified). But good observation.

Comment: subgraphs = (self.digraph.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.strongly_connected_components(self.digraph)) #<generator object